# Looping over checkboxes -PHP

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, checkbox, foreach

I have a page with around 50 input check boxes, of which their

```
name="form[]"
```

I need my php script to be able to loop through all the check boxes and which ever ones are checked and submitted I need to put into a variable so I can store which forms where given.

This is my loop :

```
if ($this->input->post('action') == 'additional') { // Checks if radio button was checked
    foreach ($this->input->post('form') as $forms) { // If above ^^^ is true loop through form[] 
        $givenforms = ', '.$forms.''; // What ever form[] is in the array assign them to the givenforms variable
    }
    $comments = 'This student was given'.$givenforms.''; // The comment I want to store in the database
}
```

This works but for only one form (check box). If for some reason my client needs to give a student all 50 forms I want the $comment = 'This student was given ...................................................(all 50 forms)'

Any links or a tip would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is CodeIgniter right? It is better to add the framework to the tags as well.

Comment: Oh, so sorry! I will do that right now!

Comment: Also just to add on, both answers produce the same exact result! Fabricio just answered first.

Comment: I find `implode` more practical and you don't have to worry about removing a leading or trailing `, ` which a for loop usually generates. `=]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're overwriting the value in each iteration with `=` instead of concatenating `.=`, but I believe you can use [`implode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) for your use case:

```
if ($this->input->post('action') == 'additional') { // Checks if radio button was checked
    $givenforms = implode(', ', $this->input->post('form'));
    $comments = 'This student was given'.$givenforms;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`$givenforms = ', '.$forms.'';` is wrong, beacause each run through the loop will overwrite the previous.
Use `.=` (concatenation operator) instead of `=`.

Also make sure to set the variable by using `$givenforms = "";` outside the loop before concatenating it using `$givenforms .= ...........`

If you don't do this you will get a warning (or notice, not sure).

Comment: I had changed that, but Rixhers commited an edit at the same time about something else.